# Pygame clicking on tiles

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a Tower Defense game in pygame. I have my background set up and the map is a set of tiles blitted in this way:

```
for x in range(0,640, tile_size): #x starta od 0 i mice se po 32 sve do 640
    for y in range (0, 480, tile_size): #y isto
        window.blit(Tile.Grass, (x,y)
```

Now it's easy to get the mouse position through:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
    print('Click')
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    print(pos)
```

But the tiles are 20 by 20 and I need to somehow be able to determine the center position of the tile, so that I can load up my rects and sprites at the proper place.

Comment: They're finally making BTD6! ;)

Comment: Srsly?? All hail bloons TD!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have stored the tiles in a list. You can floor divide the event coordinates to get the indices of the tiles in your list. For example, if you click at (164, 97) and floor divide these coordinates by the tilesize (20), you get the indices (8, 4) and can use them to swap out the tile.

```
import itertools
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')
tilesize = 20
IMG1 = pg.Surface((tilesize, tilesize))
IMG1.fill((0, 70, 170))
IMG2 = pg.Surface((tilesize, tilesize))
IMG2.fill((180, 200, 200))
img_cycle = itertools.cycle((IMG1, IMG2))

# A list of lists of lists which contain an image and a position.
tiles = []
# I create a checkerboard pattern here with the help of the `next`
# function and itertools.cycle.
for y in range(20):
    row = []
    for x in range(30):
        # I add a list consisting of an image and its position.
        row.append([next(img_cycle), [x*tilesize, y*tilesize]])
    next(img_cycle)
    tiles.append(row)

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Use floor division to get the indices of the tile.
            x = event.pos[0] // tilesize
            y = event.pos[1] // tilesize
            print(event.pos, x, y)
            if event.button == 1:  # Left mouse button.
                # Replace the image at indices y, x.
                tiles[y][x][0] = IMG1
            elif event.button == 3:  # Right mouse button.
                tiles[y][x][0] = IMG2

    # Blit the images at their positions.
    for row in tiles:
        for img, pos in row:
            screen.blit(img, pos)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pg.quit()
```

Comment: thats brilliant I didnt even think of it .Thanks